# Detect removal of open serial port devices (Qt / Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, serial-port

I have a Qt app which communicates with a dongle via serial (it's an FTDI chip). I poll `QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()` to detect when ports are added or removed, and then send the dongle a blank line to identify it (my dongle responds to this with its ID, I'm banking on it being harmless to 99% of other devices).

This all works fine, *except* that if you remove the dongle while the connection is active, it seems like the connection isn't closed and the port is still returned in `QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()`.

**Does anyone know how to detect the serial dongle's removal while I have a connection to it (other than hacks like pinging it).**

I've tried listening for all the signals `QSerialPort` emits (`error()`, `readChannelFinished()`, etc.) but none of them are emitted when you pull the dongle out. This is on Windows 7 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same issue with Qt 5.4.1, but only on Windows 7. On Windows 8 the removal of the dongle is detected.

It is actually the problems of the windows 7 itself. If you check with Device Manager you can notice that COM port remains on the list, if it has been open even in the case when dongle is removed.